# How to manually remove preload fonts settings in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

We had some plugin installed that preloads fonts.
We do no use the plug in anymore but in the console we have errors like this (see also the screenshot):

> GET ../wp-content/themes/fonts/libre-franklin-v7-latin-800.woff2
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

This is probably caused by the preload plugin.
We do not remember the name of the plugin since we have tried out several.

Question is: how can we manually remove traces of this plugin (and others)?
[image]

Comment: There’s no generic answer. It depends on the plugin. You’re going to need to start by deactivating them until the error goes away.

Comment: Is this a <link rel="preload"> on the page? You could search all of your files and database for the name of the font (I'd guess wp_options values in the database) to try and find where it's getting the name from, and if it's database which code in the site reads that value, or search all of your files for "preload" and try and find the code that generates the tag that way.

Comment: @JacobPeattie as stated in the original question: The plugin has been uninstalled. We forgot it's name.

Comment: @Rup I have added a screenshot. The errors seem to be generated by js. Correct?

Comment: Right, yes, the webfontloader.js script. That should be easy to find in your files, or if it's not there then you're probably loading it from a CDN. You should be able to see that in your page's view source, or find "webfontloader" in your site's files.

Comment: I don't see webfontloader.js myself: it looks like it's an out-of-date minified CSS in the litespeed cache.

Comment: @Rup Thank you. Although I am not sure what I am doing, I have downloaded the plugin "OMGF | Optimize My Google Fonts" and played around a little bit. Also, I have created the folder .../wp-content/themes/fonts/ which appeared to be missing. I have manually downloaded the whole Libre-Franklin font family to this folder. Again, I don't know what I was doing, but the errors are gone. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: The issue appeared to be in the theme stylesheet. Solution was: delete manually added fonts in theme stylesheet and completely delete and reinstall OMGF plugin. Use auto optimize setting. Thanks everybody for getting me on track!

Answer (score 1):

The issue appeared to be in the theme stylesheet.
Solution was: delete manually added fonts in theme stylesheet and completely delete and reinstall OMGF plugin.
Use auto optimize setting of OMGF.
Thanks everybody for getting me on track